# How to handle migrations in Django project in production (Digital Ocean App Platform)?

Tags: django, migration, digital-ocean, vps

I have been using the app platform for almost 2 months. Yesterday, I made some changes in database tables (models) in my Django projects. I pushed those changes to Github and my app successfully redeployed. But When I open the site, I got “ProgrammingError” that some field that I created new in the existing table does not exist. So, I opened the console in App Platform and applied migrations but nothing is changed. I am still facing the error.

Here is the full traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

> The above exception (column products_subcategory.description does not exist
> LINE 1: ...subcategory"."id", "products_subcategory"."name", "products_...
> ^
> ) was the direct cause of the following exception:
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
> return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/workspace/lavisco/views.py", line 40, in get
> return render(request, 'lavisco/index.html', context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
> content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
> return template.render(context, request)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
> return self.template.render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
> return self._render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
> return compiled_parent._render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 192, in render
> return template.render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 172, in render
> return self._render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 311, in render
> if match:
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in **bool**
> self._fetch_all()
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
> self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in **iter**
> results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
> cursor.execute(sql, params)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
> return super().execute(sql, params)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
> return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
> return executor(sql, params, many, context)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in **exit**
> raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
> File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

> Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
> Exception Value: column products_subcategory.description does not exist
> LINE 1: ...subcategory"."id", "products_subcategory"."name", "products_...

Comment: Add the _full_ stack trace of the error to your question.

Comment: Did you run manage.py migrate and restart your web server?

Comment: @rob I have run python manage.py migrate but "no migrations to apply" and yes, I have restarted the web server